# I am a minor, my father is abroad but I need his permission to travel

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, egyptian-citizens, vfs-global

I have a question concerning the Schengen visa to Italy. My brother and I are minors. We are planning to visit Italy in August. My father is abroad for work and I know that for all minors both parents have to sign the acceptance of their sons travelling.

But how?

My mother can do this but my father is abroad in an remote area not near to an Egyptian Embassy [as we are Egyptians] or Consulate.

How can he gives us the acceptance?

He's only near to a desk used to send the documents for visas to the Italian Embassy [like VFS Global].

Can this desk can be used to give us the acceptance or what kind of document is required and accepted by the Embassy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your father needs to send a notarized letter to the embassy stating his details, details of you and your brother stating that he authorizes you both to travel.

The details should have your complete name (as listed in your passport) along with your passport details (like passport number / expiry date); and his details and a copy of his passport or other government identification. If you already have an application reference number - that should be added as well.

The letter should be in English (and can be translated to Italian, but the translation should be certified) and it should be notarized / endorsed.

He should seal the letter in an envelop and then have it delivered directly to the agency that's processing your documents; ask them what is the best way.

If that's not possible, he can have the letter delivered to you directly, as I doubt the VFS office at your father's location can assist much. You can then submit it along with your normal paperwork.

Comment: @ Burhan Khalid! Another question please! How to notarize the letter. How can my father the letter from his country abroad?

Comment: Your father needs to visit a [public notary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary_public). There is no clear cut standard of who is considered a public notary; so it differs from place to place. It is best for your father to check with the municipality of the area where he is in, as to what constitutes a public notary. If nothing else, he can call the Egyptian embassy to find out about a public notary - most of the times, the embassy can also notarize documents.